# Update backend model of product attribute with setup script

Tags: product-attribute, magento-1, setup-script

I need to add the `backend_model` value of an attribute where wasn't specified in the install setup script. The missing line is:

```
'backend' => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_datetime'
```

But so far using just this line in an upgrade script

```
$installer  = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup', 'catalog_setup');
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_product', 'custom_date', array(
'backend' => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_datetime'));

$installer->endSetup();
```

Is not updating the column `backend_model` in the ear_attribute table. So I'm forced to use

```
$installer  = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup', 'catalog_setup');

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->removeAttribute('catalog_product','custom_date');

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'custom_date', array(
    'label' => 'Launches - Release Date',
    'type'      => 'datetime',
    'input'     => 'date',
    'class'     => 'validate-date',
    'global'    => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'required'  => false,
    'user_defined' => false,
    'searchable' => false,
    'filterable' => false,
    'comparable' => false,
    'visible_on_front' => false,
    'unique' => false,
    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
    'backend' => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_datetime'
));

$installer->endSetup();
```

Any idea if is actually possible to update the `backend_model` in an upgrade script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution replacing *backend* to *backend_model* but looks like a bug of Magento.

```
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_product', 'custom_date', 'backend_model', 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_datetime');

$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_product', 'custom_date', 'backend', 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_datetime');

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: still not working looks with this code. Even is the most logical